# Resize Image() object with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, background

I have an image object in javascript, which I am using as the background of a pong game. However, the image is larger than the canvas, so I attempted shrinking it with this

```
var bg=new Image(); 
bg.src='bg.png';
bg.width=600;
bg.height=400;
```

However, in the canvas, the image did not change sizes. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Silly question, but: did you use `bg` to draw the image? (If you did, how are you drawing the image?)

Comment: I did  ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: As an aside, @scrblnrd3, if you figure out the answer on your own, you can/should post it as an answer to your own question and accept it so others who come by here in the future quickly see that there is an answer. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: @JasCav Thanks. I've moved it to my own answer

Comment: new Image(600, 400) does not work either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resize the entire image, instead of resizing it manually from the source, add the width and height parameters into the `drawImage()` method, like this

```
 ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0,600,400);
```

Comment: Where comes ctx from?